# $\oint_C\frac{1+e^z}{z}dz$ with |z|=1 evaluate the given integral along the indicated closed contour.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Consider $\oint_C\frac{1+e^z}{z}dz$ with   |z|=1.

evaluate the given integral along the indicated closed contour.

I think this can be solve by using Cauchy's formula. But i'm not sure.

If I take$ f(z)=1+e^z$, i found the answer  ==> $2πi*f(0+0i)$=$\oint_C\frac{1+e^z}{z}dz$

Is my answer and solution way correct or not?

Comment: Yes, provided that the contour is positively-oriented.

Comment: Why did you write $0+0i$ instead of just writing $0$?

Comment: It can be just 0 too. They are the same